# How to use a Link table with Active Record query interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am still relatively new to Active Record and have a (hopefully simple) question.

I have four tables `Recipes`(Name of recipe), `Food`(lettuce, Pepper), `Units`(oz, tbsp), and `Ingredients`(Id's of the other tables and the numeric quantity).

What I'd like to do is something like this `Recipes.Ingredients` and get "Peppered Lettuce, 5 tbsp pepper, 10 oz Lettuce".

How would I accomplishes that with the following schema. And if not possible with this schema what should I build in its place.

The Schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "food", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "recipes_id"
    t.bigint "units_id"
    t.bigint "food_id"
    t.decimal "quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["food_id"], name: "index_ingredients_on_food_id"
    t.index ["recipes_id"], name: "index_ingredients_on_recipes_id"
    t.index ["units_id"], name: "index_ingredients_on_units_id"
  end

  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "units", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: Have you read [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)?

Comment: Yes. It's what helped me design this. However, I'm still struggling to conceptualize it all and put it to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what I understand from your question is you want to get results like: 
`Peppered Lettuce, 5 tbsp pepper, 10 oz Lettuce` in which Peppered Lettuce is `Recipe` name, and Pepper and Lettuce are `Food` items with numeric quantities of ingredients.

You don't need 4 tables to obtain this result. You only need 3. `Food`, `Recipe` and an in-between table for their many-to-many association.

`Recipe` can have multiple `Food` items in it and 1 `Food` item can be a part of multiple `Recipe` objects. So `Food` and `Recipe` model will have a `many-to-many` association. And for this kind of association, you need another table. You can name it `Foods_Recipes` or simply `Ingredients`.
Your `Ingredient` model will then have a `food_id`,`recipe_id`,`numeric_quantity` and `unit_type`

The Schema would look like this:

```
create_table "foods", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "recipe_id"
    t.bigint "food_id"
    t.decimal "quantity"
    t.string "unit_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["food_id"], name: "index_ingredients_on_food_id"
    t.index ["recipe_id"], name: "index_ingredients_on_recipe_id"
  end

  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
  end
```

Your models would look like this: 
Food model:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :ingredients
 has_many :foods,through: :ingredients
end
```

Ingredient model:

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :recipe
 belongs_to :food
end
```

Food model:

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :ingredients
 has_many :recipes,through: :ingredients
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll let you know how it works out for me. Is there a reason you say 2 tables instead of 3?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I said 2 tables earlier and then I realized we need a third in-between table for associations. updating my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Food pluralizes to foods. And apparently recipe_id and food_id need to be singular in the ingredients table. The query "Recipe.first.ingredients.count" errored because it was singularizing those ids.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That got me where I wanted to be.